# Java 11 : Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile failed.: NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, java-11, maven-compiler-plugin, module-info

I am upgrading  my project from java 8 to java 11. I'm able to build and deploy it with java11, spring 5 dependencies but when I am adding module-info.java into my project I am getting below error while build :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project infrastructure: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project infrastructure: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.preparePaths (CompilerMojo.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:787)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

```
Cannot find ArtifactResolver with hint: project-cache-aware
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
  roleHint: project-cache-aware
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.repository.DefaultRepositoryAssembler.contextualize (DefaultRepositoryAssembler.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.contextualize (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.activate (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler.schedule (BeanScheduler.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.manage (PlexusLifecycleManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBeanBinder.afterInjection (PlexusBeanBinder.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.notifyListeners (MembersInjectorImpl.java:131)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next (Collections.java:4210)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.repository.DefaultRepositoryAssembler.contextualize (DefaultRepositoryAssembler.java:721)
```

I have added maven-compiler-plugin as below in my pom file :

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>
 </properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>${java.version}</release>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please guide me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Just to start excluding unwanted discrepancies, remove the `source` and `target` properties and tags if they are all same as the `release`. Though it would also be really helpful to have a minimal reproducible example of your code here. e.g. Do you have `maven-assembly` configured as well?

Comment: What is the Plexus container version?

Comment: Upgrade to most recent version of maven-compiler-plugin...also if you are using JDK11 you only need to set release...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug in `Maven-Compiler-Plugin`

Have a look at the below issues:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-355
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-359

specifically at line number `CompilerMojo.java:244`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.preparePaths (CompilerMojo.java:244)
```

MCOMPILER-355 is fixed in version **3.8.1**. 
 
MCOMPILER-359 fix will be part of the next release https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/pull/28/files

You should try updating the version of `Maven-Compiler-Plugin` to **3.8.1**.

Comment: Thanks a lot....Upgradeing maven-Compiler-Plugin to 3.8.1 resolved this issue

Answer (score 1):

For me updating `maven-compiler-plugin` to version `3.8.1` was not enough.
I had also this issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216202

To fix this I had add to the maven-compiler-plugin this configuration: `forceJavacCompilerUse`

For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```