# Batik creates a Null Pointer Exception when added in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, batik

I have a Java project in Java 11, compiled with Maven 3.5.4. I would like to use Batik to work with some SVG files, but as soon as I add it in the POM file my project does not compile anymore. I get a NullPointerException from Maven. Here is the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project designfx: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project designfx: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.preparePaths(CompilerMojo.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:787)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    ... 25 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

And here is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>charm-glisten</id>
        <name>charm-glisten Repository</name>
        <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!--  JavaFX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>15-ea+6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- GluonHQ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-down-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Batik (for SVG files) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
                
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>path.to.main.class</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It already took me way too long to find what was actually creating the exception, and now I am desperate and clueless to understand why it happens...

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041989/java-11-execution-default-compile-of-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compi?

Comment: Yup, solved the problem. Thanks!